# Растяжение Image во всю ширину экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет!

У меня есть image, который должен растягиваться во всю ширину экрана (Через привязки делать не вариант), делаю я это через скрипт, изменяя ReactTransform:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<ReactTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(Display.widgth, height);
```

Данный скрипт отлично работает, и изменяет параметр width в  ReactTransform. Проблема в том, что картинка не растягивается так, как это должно быть. Например, в эдиторе я ставлю размер экрана 720x1200(720 - ширина), ReactTransform'y присваивается значение 720, но картинка почемуто не растягивается на весь экран, она остаётся по середине (Привязка у неё стоит к центру), если я вручную начинаю изменять её то для заполнения всей ширины экрана, ей требуется присвоить гораздо большее значение, нежели то значение, которое возвращает Display.width, почему это происходит? И как можно отследить "настоящие" размеры canvas

Comment: `гораздо большее значение` какое? какой исходный размер изображения при этом?

Comment: @aepot width и height и задают исходный размер. В unity есть просто белый квадрат, который можно покрасить в разный цвет и который будет = width и height от ReactTransform

Answer (score 0):

Указание размера через редактор самый правильный вариант, причем с использованием `AspectRation` для сохранения пропорций при любом соотношении сторон экрана. Если он ва не подходит, это значит что скорее всего вы ваш косяк.

Размер канваса не в размерах экрана а измеряется согласно `CanvasScaler`.

```
RectTransform rect = transform as RectTransform;
RectTransform parentRect = rect.parent as RectTransform;
rect.deltaSize = parentRect.deltaSize;
```

Comment: не работает, вообще ничего не происходит

Comment: соглашусь, что самый правильный вариант - это указание размера через редактор, просто в таком случае у меня неккоректно отображается картинка в горизонтальном режим, поэтому было принято такое решение, для наглядности записал видео: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/5YaCQY07za_61Q

Comment: заметил что в видео не отображается окно game, но проблема итак видна

Comment: Можете пожалуйста сказать как можно рассчитать размер канваса

Comment: Если ваша проблема в том, что при переходе в горисонтальный режи текст становится мельче, то это из за того что координатная цель(значение) по высоте сохраняется. Решается настройкой CanvasScaler, разберитесь как о работает.

Comment: нет, моя проблема в том, что при горизонтальном режиме картинка заходит за рамки канваса (видно на видео)

Comment: Ну так у тебя rect так настроен, right, left, height...

Comment: У меня он настроен на растяжку по всему экрану, да и вообще сложно там с этим канвасом....

Answer (score 0):

С помощью RectTransform канваса я нахожу ширину канваса:

```
rt.rect.size.x //rt - RectTransform канваса
```

далее, у меня всё ровно не сходилось, и картинка выходила за рамки, как в этом видео: disk.yandex.ru/i/5YaCQY07za_61Q
Это удалось пофиксить тем, что я поделил `rt.rect.size.x` на ширину картинка, при которой она выглядит адекватно, далее составил такой код:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(rt.rect.size.x/1.28f, this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y); //1.28f - результат деления
```

> хоть где-то пригодились знания математики (хотя такое я вспомнил с курсов физики)